# MySQL function to quote identifiers with backticks

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a MySQL built-in function that surrounds indentifiers (simple or qualified) with backticks? I.e. such function `f` would work like:

`f('my')` would return `` `my` ``,

`f('my.table')` would return `` `my`.`table` ``, and

`` f(`my`) `` would return `` `my` ``

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is a function of your database driver and not your database. The backticks are used by the MySQL statement parser to properly tokenize your statement, so a function that returns values like that would be meaningless since those would be strings and not table or column tokens.

Your database driver may have a function for escaping table names, and if so, use that. Otherwise you'll need to roll your own somehow.

Comment: I'm not using any driver. I'm writing a sql script to be run by the mysql client program. Backticks are part of the SQL language. Clients may or may not be able to quote identifiers, but I really wonder MySQL does not provide such a function to be executed on the server side.

Comment: I'm saying that function would have no purpose on the server-side. If you haven't delimited your variables prior to parsing, there's no way for MySQL to make sense of them after the fact. In other words, `SELECT * FROM F('my')` is not valid SQL no matter how you work it.

Comment: I see your point. Why should there be a function called after the parser that affects the parser? Completely agree. However, such function `F` still makes sense if you are passing indentifiers in variables. E.g. `SET @myColumn=F(param); SELECT @myColumn FROM ...`. If `param` is an procedure parameter and you don't know much about it, it's tricky to quote it.

Comment: The problem with that is `SELECT @myColumn` is selecting a string value, not the column itself. In other words, `SELECT \`x\` FROM \`y\`` is not the same as `SET @x = '\`x\`'` and then `SELECT @x FROM \`y\``. In the latter case you'll get, literally, `\`x\`` repeated once for each row. It's the same as `SELECT '\`x\`' FROM \`y\``.

Comment: Ok, we have digged into the heart of my problem. Consider this:
`set @x = '\`key\`'; SET @q = CONCAT('SELECT ', @x, ' FROM a_table'); PREPARE stmt FROM @q;`. If `key` is not backtick-quoted you get an error preparing the statement. As I said, '`key`' is passed as a parameter.

Comment: Although that might work, I'd be really hesitant to use that sort of approach in a production system. The maintainability of that is highly questionable. You really should be doing this outside of the SQL context. Passed as a parameter from where? How?

Comment: This would be a different approach beyond the scope of the original question. I still think a backstick quoter should exist because can be useful and helpful without having to recur outside of the SQL. Thank you for your answer. It was a constructive answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
concat('`',replace(your_identifier,'`','``'),'`')
```